# Equivalent definitions of abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

While studying abelian varieties I've seen the following definitions:

> An *abelian variety* over a field $k$ is a complete group $k$-variety.

> An *abelian variety* over a field $k$ is a smooth, connected, proper $k$-group scheme X.

Since a complete $k$-variety is nothing but a proper, geometrically integral $k$-scheme, I wonder if "smooth + connected = geometrically integral". I would like to know if this is true and also why these definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any group variety over a field, smoothness is equivalent to being geometrically reduced.it is true because you can check smoothness after a base change to algebraic closure, over an algebraically closed field smooth locus of a reduced variety is non-empty open $U$(there are several ways to see this) and then because you have a group scheme you can translate $U$ by elements of $A(k)$ and again this would be an open smooth subvariety and obviously union of this translations is the whole space.

also always we have Smooth+connected implies geometrically integral: smooth obviously implies reduced and if you take a point on the intersection of two irreducible components the variety can't be smooth at that point(because for example, the local ring at that point could not be regular).

I'm not sure why do you think separated condition has anything to do with other hypothesis because it is needed in both definitions.